# Installing Net::Pcap Mac OS X (sql ninja dependency)

Tags: c, linux, perl, cpan

So, i'm trying to install Net::Pcap, i'm always receiving the same error, i think it's related with the fact that my network device is not capturing packets:

http://pastebin.com/hbi0aeW3

I'm really stuck, searched google and found nothing at all.

Please, give me an hint here, really going nuts :(

Comment: Are you installing this under root or under your regular user? I believe on OS X you need access to a bunch of special files for libpcap to work, and regular users don't have it by default.

Comment: I am trying to install under root (using sudo su) :(
Tried several versions of Pcap

Comment: You could do a force install (cpan -e shell; force install Net::Pcap) as it seems to be mostly working.

Comment: Couldn't make that command line to be recognized, tried this one:
`perl -MCPAN -e "CPAN::Shell->force(qw(install Net::Pcap));"`
Still no success :(

Comment: Seems like Sql Ninja is not requesting more the Pcap dependency, probably is installed. If i get any problems with Sql Ninja at the end due to a bad installation of Cpan, i'll just quit trying to use this tool

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take this 100% and run your `sqlninja`.  And also, just upgrading your pearl, then all should work fine

```
sudo cpan
cpan[1]> upgrade
```

Just this and your pearl has no dependencies